# How to use Amazon DynamoDB JavaScript SDK with promise

Tags: node.js, express, promise, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with Amazon DynamoDB and Express.

I need to render a view based on the data from a Amazon DynamoDB table.

My code works fine when I work with callback API instead of trying to use promise.

But I want to use promise because to keep my code clean, otherwise I need to call `res.send()` from inside the callback of the `docClient.scan(params)`.

My code for working with promise as follows I can't figure out what is wrong;

```
async function test(params){
    AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsconfigtest.json');
    let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    await docClient.scan(params).promise();
}
```

Below is the content of the route file;

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    let scanResults ;
    let params = {
        TableName: 'dummy'
    };

    test(params).then((data,err)=>{
        console.log(data,err);
        data.Items.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
            scanResults.push({name: element.name, nodeId: element.nodeId});
            console.log(element.name + " (" + typeof element.nodeId + ")");
        });
    });

    console.log(scanResults);
    res.render("index",{nodes:scanResults});    
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main reason is your `test` function does not get back anything - You forgot `return` keyword.

But, I think the best practice is don't mix `async/await` syntax with Promise solve syntax (`.then .catch`).

This is way use `async/await`:

```
async function test(params){
    AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsconfigtest.json');
    let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    return await docClient.scan(params).promise(); // !!! You forgot return keyword
}
```

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) { // async function
  try {
    let scanResults;
    let params = {
      TableName: 'dummy'
    };

    const data = await test(params); // await for `data`
    console.log(data);

    data.Items.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
      scanResults.push({ name: element.name, nodeId: element.nodeId });
      console.log(element.name + " (" + typeof element.nodeId + ")");
    });

    console.log(scanResults);
    res.render("index", { nodes: scanResults });

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err); // handle exception
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use `promisify` from node `util`.

Something like this:

```
const util = require('util');

async function test(params){
    AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsconfigtest.json');
    let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const scan = util.promisify(docClient.scan);
    await scan(params);
}
```

The promisify function converts a function that takes a callback as its last value, and converts it into a promise, that will reject the `err` value, and resolve the `data` value (from something like `docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {})`)

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
    const params = {TableName : NOTES_TABLE_NAME};
    const notes = await util.promisify((cb) => documentClient.scan(params, cb))();
    cb(null, send(200, notes));
  }
  catch (err){
    cb(null, send(500, err.message));
  }
```

Worked for me.